# why there is an error in my box and whisker plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, classification

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-78ac52e99df0> in <module>
      1 # box and whisker plots
      2 dataset.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(2,2), sharex=False, sharey=False)
----> 3 plt.show()

NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

Above is the error code I faced when I tried to type a box and whisker plots

Here is the code

```
# box and whisker plots
dataset.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(2,2), sharex=False, sharey=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you imported the package?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: thanks @AnnaSemjén I do forget to import matplot!
thanks for the information

Comment: @rene thanks rene, this is my first time using stack overflow,i will take note on the tags in the future post!